# How can I protect Java/Javafx code from being seen by final user?

Tags: java, security, javafx, executable, confidentiality

I have been working on a project alone for more than two years for a company. The project is a really big one using rxtx to communicate with a hardware device. I used Java 8 and JAVAFX for the UI. Now it is almost finished and I am starting to search how to deliver the end user application that the company will distribute over its clients.

The problem is that the company I am working with wants the code to be non reachable when the software is between final clients hands because the Java code contains some extremely sensitive information that could have very bad consequences for the company if final clients happened to know them. The clients can literally perform actions they don’t have the right to perform.

So after searching (a lot) and thinking relatively to my case, I understood that giving a JAR obfuscated isn’t the solution. I then tried to generate a JAR and then transform it to an EXE but all I succeeded on was wrapping the JAR into EXE which does not prevent extracting the JAR and then seeing all the code easily. Finally, I found that I should use AoT compilation like GCJ compiler to produce native binary exe from my Java code but here I am stuck because after watching videos and reading articles etc I didn’t manage to find a clear way to produce the native binary exe.

I am now confused since I don’t know if I am on the right path and good direction or if I am totally wrong and there is another way of protecting the code (at least from non professional hackers, I understand that it is not possible to make it 100% safe but I am just searching for a reasonable and good way). How should I manage this final step of my work?

Comment: *"The problem is that the company I am working with wants the code to be non reachable when the software is between final clients hands because the java code contains some extremely sensitive information that could have very bad consequences for the company if final clients happended to know them. The clients can literally perform actions they don’t have the right to perform."* This sounds like a big security issue that should be fixed regardless of you being able to hide the "source code". Including sensitive info in the end product regardless of the way the info is stored is a terrible idea.

Comment: I agree with @fabian.  You are currently relying on "security through obscurity" and you're asking how to improve the obscurity part.  You should not be hiding anything in compiled source code or binaries that you would not feel comfortable leaving in plain text.  Casual hackers become professional hackers real quick if the secret is lucrative enough.  It sounds like you need a way for the hardware to verify requests are coming from your software and nowhere else.  Think about it from that perspective and see if you can come up with anything.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting it in C/C++?

Answer (score 0):

I currently work for a company that has code that we don't want anyone to have access to for the security of our clients and-- less important-- for legal reasons. ;-)

One possible solution you could look into would be to rewrite the code you deem most sensitive into a C/C++ library. It would be possible to compile this into a .so/.dll/.dylib file for the respective OSs and it would make it difficult, not entirely impossible, but difficult to decompile.

The trouble would come from learning how to access native code from Java as much of the documentation is not helpful or just simply nonexistent. This would utilize the Java Native Interface (JNI) which allows Java to, well, interface with the native (compiled C/C++) code. This would make it possible to create a Jar file that would effectively become a Java library for you to access throughout the rest of your project. The native code, however will still need to be loaded at runtime, but that's apart of learning how JNI works. A helpful link I found for JNI is http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/ (for as long as it's still a functional link).

One of our clients here where I work has a project written in Java and needed to implement our code that is unfortunately all written in C. So we needed a way to access this C/C++ code from Java. This is the way we went about solving this issue without rewriting our code in Java. But we had the benefit (?) of having already written our code in C.

This solution to write a bunch of extra code last minute in another language that I may or may not be familiar with doesn't sound like particularly fun time.

I would be curious to learn what possible problems others might see with this solution.